# How to change ToolTip binding programmatically?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I know that in XAML you can change a ToolTip's binding with...

```
<TextBlock Text="ABC" ToolTip="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" />
```

How can I set the same binding for the tooltip programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="ABC" x:Name="_textBlock" />
```

Code:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Data{ Tip="Help!" };

        Binding binding = new Binding("Tip");

        _textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try new Binding{Path="SomeProperty"}